# How many such permutation exists?

Tags: permutation

We are looking for permutations of  numbers   1,2,⋯,50, when  10 and 20 are  next to each other (in any order). How many such permutation exists?
Select one:
249
49!
5049
49!⋅2
50!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming (at least in its current form)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of permutations for 50 numbers with no conditions is 50!,

hence if we assume 10 and 20 are one number (as they have to be adjacent) we're down to 49! permutations.

finally for each permutation `x ... 10, 20, ... xn` exists a permutation `x, ... 20, 10, ...xn`

so we get a total of 2 * 49! permutation.